# Distance between two integer values

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

is there a simple method to calculate the distance between two values e.g. 10 and 30 which will result to 20. Currently I do it as follows:

```
CASE
  WHEN value_1 < value_2 THEN 
    value_2 - value_1 
  ELSE value_1 - value_2
END AS difference_predicted_days
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Absolute value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) function does the trick.

```
ABS(value1 - value2)
```